# tar can't create hardlink

Tags: tar

I have an old redhat linux (7.2) which I'm gonna  move to another(vmware) server (from the old one).
So I booted new server from DSL Linux liveCD (2003 year - because new linux has't driver for Bus Logic ), mounted new disk to /mnt/sysimage

then on the old server I've issued a command:

```
tar  -zpcf  - /  | ssh root@new-server.com "cat >/mnt/sysimage/fs.tar.gz"
```

or

```
 tar  -zpcf  - / | ssh root@new-server.com " tar -C /mnt/sysimage/ -xpzf - "
```

..doesn't matter

and got a lot of messages like this

```
tar: usr/lib/locale/vi_VN/LC_NUMERIC: Cannot hard link to `/usr/lib/locale/sq_AL.utf8/LC_NUMERIC': No such file or directory
tar: usr/lib/locale/vi_VN/LC_NAME: Cannot hard link to `/usr/lib/locale/ar_IN/LC_NAME': No such file or directory
tar: usr/lib/locale/vi_VN/LC_CTYPE: Cannot hard link to `/usr/lib/locale/ar_AE.utf8/LC_CTYPE': No such file or directory
tar: usr/lib/locale/vi_VN/LC_ADDRESS: Cannot hard link to `/usr/lib/locale/ar_AE.utf8/LC_ADDRESS': No such file or directory
tar: usr/lib/locale/vi_VN/LC_MEASUREMENT: Cannot hard link to `/usr/lib/locale/ar_AE.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT': No such file or directory
tar: usr/lib/locale/vi_VN/LC_PAPER: Cannot hard link to `/usr/lib/locale/ar_AE.utf8/LC_PAPER': No such file or directory
```

tar is trying to create hard link on file in absolute path and sure this file doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

The manual for tar provides some guidance about hard links: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/hard-links.html

The short of it is that you'll likely need to use the --hard-dereference flag when creating the tarball.

Comment: yeah,I've read about this  but as far as I understood this option available just in the newest versions of tar 

 tar: unrecognized option `--hard-dereference'
 Try `tar --help' for more information.

Comment: I'm going to compile new tar...
I'll update you
thanks :)

Comment: yes, it works with this option  . latest tar version didn't compile on my redhat box but fortunately version 1.20 (2008-04-14 - in this version hard-dereference first appeared) compiled without any problems